# Proving the root of polynomial is either an integer or irrational

Tags: number-theory

If x is a root of the polynomial
$x^m + c_1 x^{m-1} +c_2x^{m-2}+\cdots+c_m = 0$
(with the coefficients $c_1,c_2,\ldots,c_m$ all integers), then $x$ is either an integer or irrational.

My professor posed this question in class a few days ago. I'm not sure how to prove it. He told me to assume $a/b$ is a root of the polynomial and that a and b are relatively prime. I'm not sure how that helps.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem

Comment: Hint: Substitute $x=a/b$ and prove $b|1$.

Comment: If I do that i get: $a^m$ + $c_1$$a^{m-1}$$b$ +$c_2$$a^{m-2}$$b^2$+...+$c_m$$b^m$  = 0     How do I show that b divides 1?

Comment: You may have seen the case $x^2-2$ and could have tried to generalise it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
x^m + c_1x^{m-1} + c_2x^{m-2} + \cdots + c_n &=& 0 \\
\left(\frac ab\right)^m + c_1\left(\frac ab\right)^{m-1} + c_2\left(\frac ab\right)^{m-2} + \cdots + c_n &=& 0 \\
a^m + c_1a^{m-1}b + c_2a^{m-2}b^2 + \cdots + c_nb^n &=& 0 \\
a^m + b \left[c_1a^{m-1} + c_2a^{m-2}b + \cdots + c_nb^{n-1}\right] &=& 0 \\
\end{array}$$

Hence $b$ divides $a^m$.

Hence $b=\pm1$.

Comment: Thank you! Everything makes sense except that last line. If b divides $a^m$ why must b divide 1?

Comment: Because a and b are coprime

Comment: When would the roots be irrational/complex? If a is an integer wouldn't the roots always be integers since b=1?

Comment: Isn't this what we wanted to prove?

Comment: The question said prove that the root is an integer OR irrational. In what situation would an irrational root arise?

Comment: Well, when it is rational but not an integer, e.g. $\dfrac12$.

Comment: I feel as though there are two parts to the proof. One proves that the root must an integer as you have shown. I think the second part must show that if the root is not an integer then it must be irrational. Any idea how to go about that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58772/discussion-between-kenny-lau-and-shrindle).

Answer (score 2):

Take $f(x)=x^2+x+1$, roots of $f(x)$ are all complex numbers, hence contradicting the question.

Comment: Well, sure, normally irrational must be real, but in this context you can assume that non-real also counts as irrational...

Comment: or rather change the question to "real roots are either integer or irrational"

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am new to this site as I am to number theory.
Nevertheless I think this is how you would want to prove if $x$ is either a rational or an irrational.

I apologize in advance if it is difficult to read.

Suppose that: $X = x^n + Ax^{n-1}+ Bx^{n-2}+  ...+ N$,
where $\{A,B,C...\}$ are integers and $n$ is a positive integer.

Try to prove that there exists a rational root for X when evaluated $\mod p$. (p is some integer)

if $X \equiv 0 \mod{p}$ then there exists a rational root.

else $X$ does not have a rational root therefore it must be an irrational root.

Example: $x^3 - 8x + 6 (\mod 5)$

$$5k \equiv 0 \mod 5 \implies (5k)^3 - 8 (5k) + 6 \equiv 0^3 - 8*0 + 6 \equiv 1 \mod 5$$
$$5k + 1 \equiv 1 \mod 5 \implies (5k+1)^3 - 8 (5k+1) + 6 \equiv 1^3 - 8*1 + 6 \equiv 4 \mod 5$$
$$...$$

The values of $x$ produce the sequence $1,4,3,4,3,1,4,3,4,3,...$,
where $1,4,3,4,3$ is repeated.

As none of the numbers in the sequence are equal to zero there are no rational roots.

If you have time, try some other functions and see for yourself.